# Propagate hover event in ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a list and I want to detect when the user hovers over an li within it. Problem is mouseEnter doesn't seem to propagate. At the moment I'm resorting to using this:

```
// components/hover-pad.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    template: Em.Handlebars.compile('{{yield}}'),

    mouseEnter: function(){
        this.sendAction("action", this.get("ctx"));
    },

    action: function(){
        return "hover";
    }.property()
});

// components/project-picker.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    actions: {
        hover: function(ctx){
            console.log("caught propagated hover");
        }
    }
})

// templates/components/project-picker/hbs
<ul>
    {{#each project in projects}}
    <li>{{#hover-pad ctx="project"}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

This works but I really feel like I'm missing some ember enlightenment, what would a more idiomatic may to do it?

### Update

I should also mention that I want to capture clicks in addition to the hover event which means that it's not possible to use the action helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this is a more generic solution, for triggering actions in a parent view and passing in a context.

```
// components/evented-tag.js
export default Ember.Component.extend(
    function(){
        var definition = {
            template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('{{yield}}'),
        };

        var events = Ember.A(["touchStart", "touchMove", "touchEnd", "touchCancel", "keyDown", "keyUp", "keyPress", "mouseDown", "mouseUp", "contextMenu", "click", "doubleClick", "mouseMove", "focusIn", "focusOut", "mouseEnter", "mouseLeave", "submit", "change", "dragStart", "drag", "dragEnter", "dragLeave", "dragOver", "drop", "dragEnd"]);

        var self = this;
        events.forEach(function(event){
            definition[event] = function(){
                var handlerName = "_" + event;
                if(this.get(handlerName)){
                    this.sendAction(handlerName, this.get("param"));    
                }
            }
        });

        return definition;
    }()
);

// templates/components/evented-tag.hbs
{{yield}}
```

and to use:

```
// templates/components/project_picker.hbs
<ul>
    {{#each project in projects}}
        {{#evented-tag tagName="li" param=project _mouseEnter="projectHovered", _click="projectClicked"}}
            {{project.name}}
        {{/evented-tag}}
    {{/each}}
</ul>

// components/project_picker.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
 actions: {
    projectClicked: function(project){
        console.log("projectClicked");
        console.log(project);
    },

    projectHovered: function(project){
        console.log("projectHovered");
        console.log(project);
    }       
 }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
{{#view App.ClickHoverView contextBinding=item}}
   {{item}}
{{/view}}

App.ClickHoverView = Em.View.extend({
  tagName:'li',
  click:function(){
     this.get('controller').send('click', this.get('context'));
  },
  mouseEnter:function(){
     this.get('controller').send('hover', this.get('context'));
  }
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/uQopETU/2/edit

Comment: Ah, I should that I also want to capture clicks from the li. Unfortunately you can't use multiple actions on the same element so I don't think this is possible?

Comment: Ahh, just create a custom view

Comment: I already have a custom view for the component, it seems a bit excessive to create another one just to propagate an event no? I mean if I follow this pattern I'm going to end up creating an awful lot of custom views for when I just want to bind an event on an element to an action in my component. I've added another answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20576886/propagate-hover-event-in-ember/20577407?noredirect=1#answer-20578953 which shows how to use a generic custom view that allows propagation of any event from an element within a component.

Comment: I suppose my main goal is to only have one js and one hbs file per component. Any more than this seems a bit crufty and from googling around a bit it seems to be a common source of confusion when people start using ember.

Comment: I totally understand, the nice thing about using a view over a component is the block ability (aka you can change the html inside the view really easily)

Comment: That's a good point. I've reworked it to allow the block format.

Answer (score 0):

Ahhhh, you can register custom events with the App. All I had to do was add:

```
var App = Ember.Application.extend({
  customEvents: {
    "mouseover": "mouseOver"
  }
});
```

and because mouseover propagates up the views I can handle it in the parent view:

```
// components/project-picker.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    mouseOver: function(ctx){
        console.log("caught propagated hover");
    }
})
```

Comment: Only problem with this approach, it's not possible to send any context with the event so you don't know which view the click came from... Maybe it's possible to send the context somehow?

Answer (score 0):

OK, trying another approach now, this time I create a custom component which is used for each item in the list.

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    tagName: "a",
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('{{project.name}}'),

    click: function(){
        this.sendAction('projectClicked', this.get("project"));
    },

    mouseOver: function(){
        this.sendAction('projectHovered', this.get("project"));
    },

    projectClicked: function(){
        return "projectClicked";
    }.property(),

    projectHovered: function(){
        return "projectHovered";
    }.property()
});
```

then in the main component I register handlers for the actions that have been sent:

```
// components/project-picker.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    actions: {
        projectClicked: function(project){
            console.log("caught propagated hover");
        },
        projectHovered: function(project){
            console.log("caught propagated hover");
        } 
    }
})
```

This works but it still feels like there's a fair bit of cruft here, in particular the indirection on the sendAction method (calling through to another property) seems very long winded. Why not just pass the name of the action into sendAction directly? It also seems like I'm going to end up creating an awful lot of components to just dispatch events. Maybe it's possible to create a generic link that intercepts all events and sends them with the context...